# Search based on data saved in firebase realtime

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

how can I list users who logged in on the day? I have a field in the firebase where the date and time is saved. but I'm interested in filtering a search based on the current day based on the device's date using data saved in firebaserealtime? could someone tell me how can i filter using these requirements?
thanks in advance.

code to save datatime in database.

```
  //DataDia
usuarioAtual = UsuarioFirebase.getUsuarioAtual();
final DatabaseReference firebaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase();
DatabaseReference usuario = firebaseRef.child("usuarios").child(getIdentificadorUsuario() );
final String userId = user.getUid();
firebaseRef.child("usuarios").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {



        }
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String strDate = dateFormat.format(date).toString();
        firebaseRef.child("usuarios").child(getIdentificadorUsuario()).child("DataDia").setValue(strDate);


    }



    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }

});
```

code for search users

```
usuariosRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase().child("usuarios");
```

database structure

[image]

Comment: If you want to filter by date, then you should have a child that contains only that date, and not including the time.

Comment: You can use System.timeInMiliis() to store the date and then query from that

Comment: @DougStevenson HI thanks for your reply. I m changed to yyyy/MM/dd  https://imgur.com/a/jf4mnDj how to implement this filter? thanks in advance.

Comment: As you see in the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all users for a specific date, you'll need to:

1. Construct a string with that date in the format that you have it stored in the database.
2. Then run a query with that string against the property.

So something like:

```
firebaseRef.child("usuarios") // Note that there's no .child(userId) here anymore
  .orderByChild("DataDia").equalTo("2020/10/15")
  .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i("DB", ds.getKey());
            Log.i("DB", ds.child("DataDia").getValue(String.class));
        }
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `equalTo` from [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data)

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date date = YOUR_INPUT_DATE;
String strDate = dateFormat.format(date).toString();
usuariosRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase().child("usuarios");
Query q = usuariosRef.equalTo(strDate)
```